# After I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dualboot Windows 10, it shows that Disk is likely to fail soon

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown, disk

Today I struggled a lot to find a way to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual boot with my Windows 10. After several time getting freeze at the Ubuntu loading screen, I google the acpi error and change acpi=off to install Ubuntu. However, after the installation finished, Ubuntu shows me the message that [Hard disk problem detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcFyX.png), [and  Disk is likely to fail soon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAbyE.png), .

Anyone got the same problem ? Please give me some advice.
Another problem is that when I shutdown Ubuntu it is freezes at the loading screen, while I restart Ubuntu it's working fine :(.

Edit: After searching on google, I found someone with similar problem [DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON - failing now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065534/disk-is-likely-to-fail-soon-failing-now), then I did like Revexina's comment "First run sudo apt install smartmontools -y and then edit your question and add the output of this command sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sda"

And the output after I run the command `sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sda` is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrQL.png), the attribute that is failling is temperature_celsius.

Thanks for anyhelp, I really appreciate.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test for details on your dying hardware. Intermittent freezing and "struggled a lot to find a way to install" are classic symptoms of defective hardware. Please be aware the Ubuntu is NOT designed to run on defective or dying hardware, and will NOT extend it's life.

Comment: @user535733 it seems that the only problem with my hardware is the temperature, is it highly affected the performance and may lead to the risk of dying ? The temperature is about 40 - 43 celsius degrees at normal use.