# disk is likely to fail soon, read error rate problem

Tags: hard-drive, disk

Hi i get this error on my very old pc with ubuntu

[image: smart view]

[image: sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sda result]

I have to change the disk or there is something i can do?

I already readed this:
[DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON - failing now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065534/disk-is-likely-to-fail-soon-failing-now)

Comment: I had a 13 year old PC which showed this error. I had a backup of the data, so I did not replace the hard disk immediately. After three months, one day it did not boot anymore. But note that it might happen to you on the next reboot. **Take a backup immediately**.

Comment: If you ever have this kind of error message, don't hesitate: Do a backup immediately. Get a new disk. Start migrating to that new disk as soon as possible.

Comment: @user535733 The READ ERRORS **could** come from two bad blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Take a backup of anything important **now**. By the time you reboot next, all your data could be gone.

And yes, once you've backed up your data, get a new drive. Your drive has failed/is about to. Don't use it again for something else. Ideally, replace it with an SSD from a reputable brand (e.g., Samsung). If you can't, replace it with an HDD from a reputable brand (Seagate and WD/Western Digital are both good).

Answer (score 1):

**Check file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Bad block the disk...**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```